# getResources filter TV by date is not working

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I’m trying to filter items based on their TV's date using a getResources call. If the event (eventStart), is greater or less than today.

For upcoming events this works fine:

```
&tvFilters=`eventStart>>[[!getDate]]`
```

However for past events this doesn’t work:

```
&tvFilters=`eventStart<<[[!getDate]]`
```

For some reason, in my code editor (VS) the lower than arrows (<<) are shown in red and the results are not accurate. There are missing items and other items without the eventStart TV appear when they shouldn’t.

[image]

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

The past events that were missing are now showing. I needed to add the "&limit" property and set a high number as it shows only 5 by default.

Now I just need to find a way to exclude the events were the eventStart TV doesn't exist. These items shouldn't appear under past events because they don't have a specific date.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please don't worry about red arrows, syntax is correct.
2. Did you debug what date format comes inside `eventStart` TV? Maybe there is some kind of format issue, and as a result incorrect selection and sorting ... try to clarify, for example, like this:

   `` &tvFilters=`eventStart<<[[!getDate:date=`%Y-%m-%d`]]` ``

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. I already tried it before posting the question.

Comment: https://community.modx.com/t/getresources-filter-tv-by-date-is-not-working/3959/8 I completely forgot, really the default &limit=5 wasted a lot of nerves)  Thanks, Bruno!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution. I needed to set a &limit property. By default only 5 items are shown, that's why some past events were missing.

I also added a second &tvFilter condition eventStart!== to exclude resources with an empty TV eventStart.

```
&limit=`20`
&tvFilters=`eventStart<<[[!getDate]],eventStart!==`
```